# Configuração many to many code fast migration

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, migrations, fluent-api

boa tarde!

Tenho essa configuração de muitos para muitos no meu projeto.

```
public class Usuario
{
    public Usuario()
    {
        this.LocalTrabalho = new HashSet<LocalAtendimento>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<LocalAtendimento> LocalTrabalho { get; set; }
}

public class LocalTrabalho 
{
    public LocalTrabalho ()
    {
        this.Usuarios = new HashSet<Usuario>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios{ get; set; }
}


modelBuilder.Entity<LocalAtendimento>()
            .HasMany<Usuario>(s => s.Usuarios)
               .WithMany(c => c.LocalTrabalho)
               .Map(cs =>
               {
                   cs.MapLeftKey("LocalTrabalho_Seq");
                   cs.MapRightKey("Usuario_Seq");
                   cs.ToTable("LocalTrabalhoUsuario");
               });
```

Quando eu salvo um usuário ele deveria somente referenciar o local de trabalho, mas ao salvar ele cria um novo local de trabalho na tabela local de trabalho, com os mesmo dados do local de trabalho referenciado, alguém sabe como resolver?

Obrigado.

Comment: Coloca o código que faz o cadastro.

Answer (score 0):

O Entity Framework na hora da inserção de Usuário não possui tracking da sua propriedade `ICollection<LocalAtendimento> LocalTrabalho`, por causa disso ele acredita que você quer inserir novos localAtendimento, e não apenas relacionar eles.

Representação do que você provavelmente esta fazendo:

```
_contexto.Usuarios.Add(UsuarioQuePossuiColecaoPreenchida);
```

O que você precisa é fazer o Attach dessas propriedades antes de chamar o SaveChanges():

```
foreach(var local in UsuarioQuePossuiColecaoPreenchida.LocalTrabalho)
{
    _contexto.LocaisAtendimento.Attach(local);
    //A linha abaixo terá o mesmo efeito. Escolha uma.
    //_contexto.Entry(local ).State = EntityState.Unchanged; 
}
_contexto.Usuarios.Add(UsuarioQuePossuiColecaoPreenchida);
```

Quando você faz um Attach(), você esta fazendo o tracking do seu objeto novamente no estado de Unchanged, ou seja, não vai alterar seu valor e o Entity vai entender na chamada do SaveChages() que não é para inserir esses valores, e sim relacionar eles.